# MySQL OR in query

Tags: php, mysql

Can I use "OR" in a mysql statement to check a fields value against multiple options?

```
    //THE QUESTION IF HAVE IS HOW DO I DO SOMETHING LIKE BELOW  MAINLY THE "1 OR 2 OR 3 OR 4" PART.

    $sql = "SELECT email FROM USER_INFO WHERE storeID = '$storeNUM' AND region = '1 OR 2 OR 3 OR 4'";
   $results2 = $db->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `IN` as a shorthand for multiple OR tests.

```
SELECT email
    FROM USER_INFO
    WHERE storeID = '$storeNUM'
        AND region IN (1,2,3,4);
```

Comment: Thanks +1 and checked in 6 mins.

Answer (score 4):

This is how you do such a match:

```
... AND region IN (1,2,2,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$sql = "SELECT email FROM USER_INFO WHERE storeID = '$storeNUM' AND (region = 1 OR region = 2 OR region = 3 OR region = 4)";
```

Comment: Didn't downvote, but going to say that this isn't WRONG, per-se. There are better ways to do it than writing out multiple 'or' comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array and [implode](http://php.net/implode) it for a nice solution:

```
$regions = array( 1, 2, 3, 4);
$sql = 'SELECT email FROM USER_INFO WHERE storeID = "$storeNUM" AND ( region = ' . implode( ' OR region = ', $regions) . ' )';
echo $sql;
```

**Output:**

```
SELECT email FROM USER_INFO WHERE storeID = "$storeNUM" AND ( region = 1 OR region = 2 OR region = 3 OR region = 4 )
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/YlYxAD)

Comment: I would like to hear it as well. OP was asking if he can use `OR` and that's a way to use it.

Comment: I didn't down vote and your answer is how I was going to do it before the post about using  IN. Thanks for the info +1

Answer (score -1):

If region is a string, which you have it down to be, but it really has no reason to be:

```
$sql = "SELECT email FROM USER_INFO WHERE storeID = '$storeNUM' AND region REGEXP '1|2|3|4'";
$results2 = $db->query($sql);
```

Comment: No way! Why use REGEXP when `IN` is there for you?

Comment: You can us `IN` for strings, too - `select '3' in ('3','4','4');` works in MySQL.

Comment: @flexxy: you can also do `... somevalue IN (field1, field2, field3,...)` as well. It's a nice flexible operator.